# Wait for subview to be displayed, then process, then remove subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, ios8

I have spent a week trying to figure out how to do this.

What I want to do is display a subview, then do my http calls to the backend, and then after that remove the subview.

```
...
//Display view
[superView addSubview:blurredOverlay];
[superView bringSubviewToFront:blurredOverlay];

//After blurredOverlay is displayed, Try to login the user
dispatch_group_t d_group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t bg_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_async(d_group, bg_queue, ^{
    //Try to login user
    success = [self loginUser];
    NSLog(@"Success=%i", success);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.0]; //here to force thread to not return immediatly
});
dispatch_group_wait(d_group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

//Remove the view after the thread is done processing
[blurredOverlay removeFromSuperview];
```

This is not working. If I have

```
[blurredOverlay removeFromSuperview];
```

uncommented, the blurredOverlay is never display. If I comment it out, the blurredOvleray is displayed but I obviously can't remove it.

What I need is to display the blurredOverlay first, then try to login the user (while the blurredOverlay is displayed), and after the loginUser returns, remove the blurred display.

Comment: I had tried multiple different dispatch_group_async variations, but I am new to threading and nothing I did helped.

Comment: Rather than using dispatch_groups, use NSURLSession, or NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest, and remove your overlay in the completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dispatching this block to an asynchronous queue. Your main thread will not stop to wait until that block is completed. 
But you know that already. That's why you use dispatch groups to block the main thread until the background task is done.
The problem with that approach is that the UI is only refreshed after the runloop completes the current iteration. And that does not happen until your method is left.

This is what happens when your code runs:

- UI is updated by the system
- your method is entered

  - add view
  - dispatch block
  - wait for block to complete
  - remove view
- leave your method
- UI is updated by the system

You see the problem? The UI is not updated between adding the view and removing it.

Here is what you should do. You add the view. dispatch the block with your task so it runs in the background. At the end of that background block, you dispatch another block that will run when your background task is completed. That block runs on the main thread and removes your view.

```
[superView addSubview:blurredOverlay];
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    // run your web request here
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.0];

    // task is done
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // UI updates have to run on the main thread, so dispatch the removal
        [blurredOverlay removeFromSuperview];
    });
});
```

Comment: I could of sworn I tried this also. Must have not, because it works!!! The only thing now is my //web requests has AlertViews in it. It will return, get rid of the blurredOverlay but then waits until the next runloop cycle to display the alert. What i need is for the alert to display before the blurredOverlay is removed. Ill mess around with it. Thanks so much!